# PHP: $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] vs $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

I printed $_SERVER, and I found out that $`_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` vs `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` both have same values. What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

*REQUEST_URI* is the requested URI path and query as used in the [HTTP request line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1). [*REDIRECT_URL* is created by Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html#variables) when an internal redirect happens:

> `REDIRECT_` environment variables are created from the environment variables which existed prior to the redirect. They are renamed with a `REDIRECT_` prefix, i.e., `HTTP_USER_AGENT` becomes `REDIRECT_HTTP_USER_AGENT`.
>
> `REDIRECT_URL`, `REDIRECT_STATUS`, and `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` are guaranteed to be set, and the other headers will be set only if they existed prior to the error condition.

Note that *REDIRECT_URL* does only contain the URI path.

Comment: `REDIRECT_URL` returns normal url e.g. `/review`, in the other hand `REQUEST_URL` returns including query string e.g. `/review?page=4`

Comment: superb i was stuck hear for long time

Comment: @AlbertSamuel "`REQUEST_URL`" - That should be `REQUEST_URI` (with an `I`).

Answer (score 17):

`$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` is only available on some servers in some cases. Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead.

Comment: Be be aware that they might have different behaviours, since REQUEST_URI contains the query String! ( I Had a problem with my API)

Answer (score 12):

REQUEST_URI also changes special chars like spaces to "%20" etc.