# protocall-less URIs getting redirected and throwing errors in LAMP stack

Tags: php, apache, http, zend-framework, zend-server

I've been actively using the protocol-less URLs for pretty much all external content lately and everything has been working great.  I recently decided to start getting alerts for all 404s from my server and sudden was flooded with errors that had to do with linking to external content with "//".

$_SERVER output shows:

```
  ["REDIRECT_URL"]=>
  string(46) "/www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
  string(7) "CGI/1.1"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(47) "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(10) "/index.php"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(10) "/index.php"
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
  int(1373437449)
```

I'm running Zend Framework MVC, so everything is supposed to be routed to index.php for processing, but external stuff loads just fine.  Going to pages with these links throws no errors via firebug, but I'm getting flooded with errors when it redirects to the single slash "REDIRECT_URL" as seen above.

This means that:
//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js

gets redirected to: 
/www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js

which really means:  http://www.mydomain.com/www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js
which turns into an error:  Exception information - Message Invalid controller specified (www.googleadservices.com)

Since the site works and there really isn't any actual visible problems, I'm just curious why this would be happening in the background and was curious if anyone else has ever seen such a thing.

Comment: //www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js should never even hit your server, could you have added some kind of page filter that is breaking these links (if you view source on the hosting page I'm assuming you are seeing something like `<script src='/www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js'></script>`)

Comment: That's the exceptionally weird part.  Going to the page shows: 

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>`

Comment: did you recently add a base tag to your html?

Comment: I hate the base tag, never use them.

Comment: Doing a little bit of research, I've found that the [REDIRECT_URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483912/php-serverredirect-url-vs-serverrequest-uri) is generated by apache.  So I'm going to start my witch hunt there.

Comment: I would start digging on the client side...watch the request go out in the network panel of dev tools... this shouldn't even be getting to apache.... something goofy is going on with the browser.

Comment: Yes, I totally see what you mean now.  It's strange to think I would even see the \\ urls at all!  Huh.  Some of the browser types are bots, so I started to ignore them, but then, there were lots of others that looked like normal browsers too.  I'll make sure to post my answer should I ever get to the bottom of this.  Thanks, Orangepill!