# How to use REQUEST_URI instead of REDIRECT_URL with IIS to get same functionality?

Tags: php, redirect, iis, iis-7.5, php-5.3

I have PHP app with usage of **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**. If I use Apache web server my app is working fine. If I use Microsoft IIS web server App is not working, because **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** is null. I found that **$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']** is available with Microsoft IIS.

My question is how to use **$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']** instead of **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']** to get same functionality using Microsoft IIS web server?

I can not simply replace REQUEST_URI with REDIRECT_URL, as it does not contain the query string and I need that for my PHP app.

My php code:

```
function filterAppUrl($url)
{  
  $url = htmlspecialchars($url);
  $url = str_replace('"', '',  $url);
  $url = str_replace("'", '',  $url);
  return $url;
}

function setAppURL()
{
   $url = $this->filterAppUrl($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']);
   $url = substr($url, 1, strlen($url));
   $this->full_url = $url;
   $this->url = explode('/', $url);
}
```

My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My Web.config for IIS

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <remove value="index.php" />
    <add value="index.php" />
  </files>
 </defaultDocument>
<rewrite>
 <rules>
     <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
     </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
function setAppURL()
{
   if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) {
      $url = $this->filterAppUrl($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']);
   } else {
      $url = $this->filterAppUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   }
   $url = substr($url, 1, strlen($url));
   $this->full_url = $url;
   $this->url = explode('/', $url);
}
```

Which basically is like saying: if `REDIRECT_URL` is set and not null, then use it. Else use `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: No it is not working, because return values are different of REDIRECT_URL and REQUEST_URI. Also I used redirect with index.php. I updated the question with my .htaccess and Web.config to make the problem clear.

Comment: What are you saying? REDIRECT_URL and REQUEST_URI both contain values, but you can only determine which one is correct by checking the server the script is running on?

Comment: I read this: "Note that REDIRECT_URL does only contain the URI path." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483912/php-serverredirect-url-vs-serverrequest-uri I tried your code but app is not working as with apache server.

Comment: If I use your code I am having problem when my URL contains queryString like mydomain/path/item?id=1

Comment: @DmitryKazakov I see. I just clarified your question to point out that you need the query string, that was not obvious (at least not for me). Please make a script that calls `phpinfo();`, run it, and examine all available variables. Maybe that helps you to find a suitable variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and although the exact contents of the $_SERVER array seem to differ between various IIS configurations, this works for me on an Azure machine.

I use this code to get a working reference to the requested URL without a query string, on both Unix and IIS:

```
        // on unix we just get what we need
        if(isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI'])) {
            $base_uri = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI'];
        }
        // IIS doesn't have a nice way to get the request url without the query string,
        // so grab the request uri until the start of the query string
        else {
            $base_uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'));
        }
```

For an url like http://www.example.com/path/to/page?article=123, *$base_uri* will be, on both Unix and IIS, */path/to/page*.