# Explanation how to use a simple routing system in PHP

Tags: php, routes

Hello everybody I am new with Routing systems in Php. Searching on the web I have found this short code for explain how routing should work but... I cannot understand in which way It routes my request to the desired page:

```
<?php

// Get the requested path with $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'],
// and require the page you want to display. I have '' and '/' for both url.com/ and url.com.

// REDIRECT_URL returns normal url e.g. /review,
// in the other hand REQUEST_URI returns including query string e.g. /review?page=4

$request = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];

switch ($request) {
    case '/' :
        require __DIR__ . '/views/index.php';
        break;

    case '' :
        require __DIR__ . '/views/index.php';
        break;

    case '/about' :
        require __DIR__ . '/views/about.php';
        break;

    default:
        require __DIR__ . '/views/404.php';
        break;
}
```

When I open it the first time it redirect me to index.php:

```
<h1>main</h1>
```

and the other page is about.php:

```
<h1>about</h1>
```

My question is: how can I switch to about.php using the routing system?

Because If I write inside the url localhost/simpleRouter/views/about.php it looks like I am bypassing the routing system.... so I cannot figure out how can I use it properly to switch between pages. Morover, the index.php page shows me MAIN and this is good, but i receive a the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: REDIRECT_URL in
>   D:\App\xAMPP\htdocs\studio\Php\SviluppareInPHP7\CAP7\simpleRouter\index.php
>   on line 9

Thank you for answering my questions and helping me to improve my knowledge on this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for URL Rewriting. You can configure your Webserver (Apache, NGinx, ...) to redirect all or some requests, e.g. to your router.php.

[Apache URL Rewriting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)
[NGinx URL Rewriting](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

In your router.php, you can then extract the originally requested URL, e.g. `about.php`. Note that this is different to the `views/about.php`.
The "Router" then includes the specified file. This allows you to use arbitrary URLs instead of filenames.

Also check out the difference between REDIRECT_URL and REQUEST_URL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483912/php-serverredirect-url-vs-serverrequest-uri).